# Agile Method and Scrum, how I can complete this document template?

Tags: uml, scrum

I'm doing a project (website) for the university.
Right now I'm in the sprint 1.
In the template provided by my teacher I have two sections: User Stories and Product Design. In each of these two sections I have subsections: "Class diagram" and "sequence diagram". Could you let me know what is the difference between the two sections and between the two diagrams in the various sections of the same SPRINT? should not they be the same thing? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your template looks like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

- User Story

  - ClassDiagram
  - SequenceDiagram
- ProductDesign

  - ClassDiagram
  - SequenceDiagram

First,

- *ClassDiagram* is for describing static aspects (structure)
- *SequenceDiagram* is for describing dynamic aspects (behavior, interactions)

For example define classes A and B. A has methodA and B has methodB. Thats the structure you depict in the classdiagram. In the sequencediagram you describe the behavior, for example A.methodA calls B.methodB, in order to realize the function described in the story.

You could use both diagrams in various stages of your design & implementation process (i.e. during requirements analysis or during solution design), so you can use it for both: describing a story and describing a design.

Second,

I assume the homework is around an approach called "[Object Oriented Analysis and Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_analysis_and_design)" which decomposes a problem into various aspects (structured analysis) and derives an appropriate design (object oriented design), both steps use the various elements of UML.

A story could be structurally decomposed using object oriented analysis and the product design could be created using object oriented design.

So let's assume assume you have a user story "As a teacher I want to conduct exams to check the knowledge of my students".

You have an actor "teacher", a use case "conduct exams" and an actor "students". You could derive an analysis model from this:

- Class Teacher

  - conductExam()
- Class Student

  - testKnowledge()

Teacher.conductExam() -> Studen.testKnowledge()

From this analysis model you could derive a design model

- Teacher
- ExamSheets
- Student
- StudentTests
- Score
- ...

and whatever more your need to describe the solution to your problem.

The actual approach is from Rational Unified Process (RUP) and not necessarily from "agile" development which is much less structured regarding *how* you actually develop a solution. UML with all its elements is a standardized set of visual elements with a defined semantic. However the above mentioned approach is *one* way to interpret your task, I'm sure there are many others, too.

Comment: Thanks you for your response, but I don’t know because my teacher in this template https://s33.postimg.cc/m0qr3fuyn/BC1_F7881-089_C-4555-_A8_E6-8042_D4587405.jpg  put both diagram class and diagram sequence in Chapter User stories and Chapter Product design. Which is the difference ?

Comment: as written, you can use it for both. The diagrams are just "tools" you can use to describe structural and dynamic aspects. For stories you decompose and describe the requirements (the user story), for design you describe how the solution may look like.

Comment: yes but if I do class diagram in user story, I can put this diagram also in chapter product design? Can you give ma a example of diagram class in user story and class diagram for product design? This template is for sprint 1 so for the same user stories

Comment: for some cases there is a certain overlap, yes, but usually the design contains more elements than the analysis. have a look at this article, http://www.codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/e-books/umlformanagers/umlformanagers_ch3.pdf during analysis they decompose a use case into Entity,Boundary and Controller classes, and those are inputs to derive an actual product design

Comment: so if in analysis I do class diagram, in product design I can do diagram with WAE UML?  In class diagram in user story I make a general class diagram , in product design so I can rappresent with WAE a classi diagram more specific ? For sample with use of WAE , do a class diagram of my web site .? Sorry for my English. :) tanks so much

Comment: what do you mean by WAE?

Comment: Web application Extend (extended of UML)

Comment: ah, in that case, yes, you're right, use WAE UML for product design, and Boundary,Controller,Entity classes for analysis. Actually the Boundary is your Web UI which you can detail with WAE, Servlet maps to the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

A class or sequence diagram is the same in both contexts; so, it doesn't have any sense that you have to do some diagrams for user stories and others for the product design... You only have a product (software) and those diagrams must represent that product.

Besides, we are talking about to completely different topics here: Those diagrams are related to UML, a common language to abstract and represent software design concepts. The user stories are usually related to SCRUM (or any other Agile method), which is used to provide a formal way to develop software.

Both diagrams are concepts related to product design (software). Those are just tools to represent in an abstract way some concepts of your product.

User stories are used to represent requirements or work to be done in order to complete your product. For example, a user story could be "Create a view where a visitor could create an account", "create a login view for registered users" or "Create the **class diagram** to represent the relationship between entities in your product" and "create a **sequence diagram** to represent the interaction". Do you see it now?

In my opinion, you have to do your class and sequence diagram (once) and, of course, this is part of the product design phase, but since you are using user stories to represent the tasks to be done to complete your product, you are going to have two user stories that say something like this:

- Create the class diagram for the product
- Create the sequence diagram for the product
- Create something else for my project.

Answer (score -1):

I second Thisisalexis. They are 2 different topics UML & Scrum. User stories are nothing but small concise representation of requirement in a user narration. Agile makes things playful and hence lightweight and fun. The best aspect of Agile.

While boht Class Diagrams and Sequence Diagrams should come under Product Design.
User stories description can have reference to one or more of Product design templates, consisting of Class &/or Sequence diagrams.

I tried to keep it short and simple. Hope this helps :)